# which are Navigation Techniques in Android?

Tags: android

What are Different **Navigation Techniques** or **View Flow** in Android ? (like Circle Flow Indicator, Scrolling Tab etc)

Comment: Have you googled it ?

Comment: In this order : Navigation drawer -> Action Bar Drop down -> Tabs (This is just google advice, anyway you can do as you want) If you want more ideas take a look at well known applications ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the Goofy and his comment that you should do Google and try to explore [d.android.com](http://developer.android.com/index.html) first.

Still I would suggest you to look into the [Google I/O Android app](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/):

- Google I/O 2013: Its implemented with Tab + Swipe View
- [Google I/O 2014](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.iosched): It's implemented with Navigation Drawer and Card design.